# How to show specific form of matrix for linear operator?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am given linear operator $\;T:V\to V\;$, with $\;\dim_{\Bbb R}V=3\;$, and I am told  $\;T\neq0\;,\;\;T^2=0\;$ .

I already know this means $\;\dim\,\text{Im}\,T=1\;,\;\;\dim\,\ker T=2\;$ , and I am asked to prove there exists basis $\;B\;$ of $\;V\;$ such that the matrix representation of $\;T\;$ in this basis is

$$[T]_B=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

*This I have done so far*: I choose basis $\;\{v_1,v_2\}\;$ of $\;\ker T\;$ , and I then take basis $\;\{v_3\}\;$ of $\;\text{Im}\,T\;$. Then it is easy to check that $\;C=\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}\;$ is linearly independent and thus basis of $\;V\;$, and it is close to what I need but the problem is I only know that $\;Tv_3=kv_3\;$ , and then

$$[T]_c=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&k\end{pmatrix}$$

and I can't find a way to get an element for which $\;Tu=u\;$ and then get a $\;1\;$ in entry $\;1-3\;$ as needed and also to get that one in the correcto position.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Matrix form of your $[T]_c$ doesn't mean $Tv_3=kv_3$, it means $Tv_3 = kv_1$. Also, $v_3$ as defined has a form of $Tu$ (image is a set of "values" of $T$) and thus $Tv_3 = 0$.

Comment: @Abstraction Thank you, that is right. I shall correct.

Comment: You seemingly didn't. Note that $\text{Im} \, T \subset \ker T$ and your $C$ is not a basis.

Comment: @Abstraction Ah, yes. Now I see: $\;T(\text{Im}\,T)=0\implies \text{Im}\,T\le\ker T\;$ . Well, that clears things a little. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v_3$ be a vector not in $\ker T$, $v_1 = Tv_3 \in \ker T$, $v_2$ complements $v_1$ to a basis of $\ker T$. Then $C = \{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ is a basis and matrix of $T$ in it is $$[T]_C = \pmatrix{0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0}$$

Comment: Great. After your comment it really became clearer. Thank you very much. +1